# 2 files are combined on a single column but at different column numbers using awk

Tags: awk

My requirement is 2 files are compared like this  2nd field of 1st file and last field on 2nd file and the matched record from the 2nd file should write in to the new file.

Can anyone provide the solution for this?

file1:

```
aaa,ABC123
bbb,ABC234
ccc,ABC789
```

file2:

```
123,QWER124,HHHHH,YYYYY,ABC123
145,WWWW12,HHHTLR,IEIRJ,ABC2345
125,SJHJSD,HJHJ,OOOP,ABC789
```

Desired output is

```
123,ABC123,QWER124,HHHHH,YYYYY
125,ABC789,SJHJSD,HJHJ,OOOP
```

Comment: If your problem is solved, you should accept the answer.

Comment: i am new to this forum can you please tell me how to accept is there any voting option or something like that to accept this solution?

Comment: Click the check mark ✔ next to jaypal's answer to accept it.

Comment: @unixuser In your example, why the second line in the 2nd file (ABC234) is not printed in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
NR==FNR { fld[$2] = $1; next }
($2 in fld) { print $1, fld[$2], $2, $3, $4, $5 }
' file1 file2
123,aaa,ABC123,QWER124,HHHHH,YYYYY
125,ccc,ABC789,SJHJSD,HJHJ,OOOP
```

We set the input and output field separator in the `BEGIN` block. `FS=OFS=","` sets it to `,`. `NR==FNR` allows us to read the file1 first. We create an array `fld` that holds the value of column1 with key of column2. Once the file1 is read completely, we move to file2. We check if the second column exists in our array. If it does we just print them as per your output.

Comment: Thank you,Jaypal
We create an array fld that holds the value of column1 (with key of column2) can you please elaborate more on this statement in brackets???

Comment: @unixuser Arrays in `awk` are associative which means the indices are basically keys (strings). When we are reading the first file, we use column2 ($2) as the keys of our array whose value is column1 ($1).